# Array comparison is always returning false in Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops

I am trying to compare 2 nested arrays but it is always returning `false`.

I want to do a comparison such that `saleLineList` in each `saleBlock` of `this.saleBlockList` is equal to the `saleLineList` in each `saleBlock` of `saleBlockList`.

Even if I modify the data it is still returning `false`. I have spent a lot of time on this but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help me. Thanks

```
let check = saleBlockList.every(item => this.saleBlockList.every(saleBlock => saleBlock.saleLineList == item.saleLineList)) 

console.log('check', check)
```

Comment: `findIndex()` returns a integer, not a boolean. So unless the match is at the 0th element, that will always be coerced to `true`. It would help to see a small example of your dataset in order to more accurately debug this

Comment: missing context on the code

Comment: are you trying to check if two arrays are equal `saleBlock.saleLineList == item.saleLineList`

Comment: `let check = saleBlockList.every(item => !!this.saleBlockList.find(saleBlock => JSON.stringify(saleBlock.saleLineList) === JSON.stringify(item.saleLineList)))` if order of inner arrays does matter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your list is structured but I think you should use:

```
let check = saleBlockList.every(item => this.saleBlockList.findIndex(saleBlock => saleBlock.saleLineList == item.saleLineList)) 
console.log('check', check)
```

instead of

```
let check = saleBlockList.every(item => this.saleBlockList.findIndex(saleBlock => saleBlock.saleLineList === item.saleLineList)) 
console.log('check', check)
```

if that doesn't work, then please provide more code for help